# imagepng() and transparency in GD library with PHP

Tags: php, gd

When using the function `imagepng()` in PHP, how can I make sure the images that I save are saved with a transparent background?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example of the [`imagecolortransparent`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php) function (if it helps):

```
<?php
// Create a 55x30 image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(55, 30);
$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

// Make the background transparent
imagecolortransparent($im, $black);

// Draw a red rectangle
imagefilledrectangle($im, 4, 4, 50, 25, $red);

// Save the image
imagepng($im, './imagecolortransparent.png');
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: Eric beat me to it here.  Later on the same page, someone comments, "When you use palette images (created with imagecreate()), the first color allocated is the background color. This color cannot be used for transparency. So if you want to make the background transparent, first allocate a dummy background color, then allocate the real background color and declare this is as transparent."

Answer (score 57):

Simply do this:

```
imagealphablending($img, false);
imagesavealpha($img, true);
```

Before outputting. Make sure that all source files (if you used any) are set to PNG 32-bit with transparency - if not the output may differ with black background or transparency does not comply.

Comment: Transparency is often called "alpha".

Comment: The accepted solution didn't worked as expected, but this one is perfect!

Comment: Yep, after the above solution from Eric didn't really do anything, this worked right off the bat.

Comment: Another question is, [how to save the output image into a different directory, with a new filename and extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30331812/4883372)

Answer (score 18):

Here is the example

```
     $newimage = imagecreatetruecolor($dst_w, $dst_h);
     imagealphablending($newimage, false);
     imagesavealpha($newimage, true);
     $transparentindex = imagecolorallocatealpha($newimage, 255, 255, 255, 127);
     imagefill($newimage, 0, 0, $transparentindex);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a function called [imagecolortransparent](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php) that allows you to set which color is made transparent. I don't know if this answers your question.