# Image Overlay in PHP; Black Background?

Tags: php, image, background, overlay

When I perform and image overlay in php using the GD library, I always get a black background, however, all the images overlay correctly. Can someone help?

```
<?php

    $images = array( $_GET['color'], $_GET['face'], $_GET['hat'] );


    $img = imagecreatetruecolor(58, 75);

    imagealphablending($img, true);
    imagesavealpha($img, true);

    imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 205, 255);
    imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
    imagecolortransparent($img, $white);

imagefilledrectangle($img, 0, 0, $imgWidth, $imgHeight, $white);
    foreach($images as $fn) {

        $cur = imagecreatefrompng($fn);
        imagealphablending($cur, true);
        imagesavealpha($cur, true);


        imagecopy($img, $cur, 0, 0, 0, 0, 58, 75);


        imagedestroy($cur);
    }   


    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($img);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Create an image

$img = imagecreatetruecolor($imgWidth, $imgHeight);

$white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);

// Make the background white

imagefilledrectangle($img, 0, 0, $imgWidth, $imgHeight, $white);
```

...could help.

Comment: I edited the post's script to my newest script. Still shows black.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem, and the answer is already available on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705098/php-imagepng-and-transparency); the answer there fixes the problem perfectly.  You may want to try searching harder :)

I would suggest that you can make your life easier by using the vastly more powerful (but unfortunately poorly documented) [imagick](http://au.php.net/imagick) library if you're going to try to do anything more than the most basic image manipulation; it's faster, easier (again, once you get past the documentation) and more powerful.

Comment: I have been searching for 3 days, and nothing seemed to work.

Comment: @Seth: As noted in the discussion El Yobo linked, you should allocate a dummy color before allocating the white as you cannot use the first allocated color as transparency. Also, you use `$white` in your code before defining it.