# PNG manipulation removes transparency

Tags: php

I am simply trying to return an PNG image through PHP, but I have a problem with the transparency not showing right. (Basically one PHP file will be capable of returning any of my images.)

I use simple code to return the image:

```
<?php
    $im = imagecreatefrompng("images/fakehairsalon.png");
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

The original image looks like this:
[image: Original image]

And the one returned via PHP (and that piece of code) looks like this:
[image: Messed up image]

Is there anything I can do to prevent this and make the image come through normal?

Comment: There has been a similar question with answer right here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705098/php-imagepng-and-transparency][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705098/php-imagepng-and-transparency

Comment: I know, read through all these, but they seem to 'save' the images etc... I only want to return (pass it along) to the browser

Comment: @Alvaro, I am not trying to manipulate the image, only to pass it along to the browser

Comment: true, my bad..
Temporarly saving it and returning that one might be a workaround?

Comment: @bjorn then there's no need to throw it through php!

Comment: @Nideo: don't use image manipulation functions then. Pick your favourite [file system function](http://es.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) instead, such as [readfile()](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

Comment: @Alvaro & Dunhamzzz , The purpose is a bit more complex than that snippet of code, there will be calculations etc to determine which image to display, and then the relevant image will be passed back. But anyhow, it works fine now with Alvaro's answer below. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in a [user comment](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php#85754), you must do this:

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng("borrame.png");
header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagealphablending($im, true); // setting alpha blending on
imagesavealpha($im, true); // save alphablending setting (important)

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

**Update:** This answer was assuming that your code is an except from a bigger script you are using to do on-the-fly image manipulation.

If you don't want to *change* the original file, this is a plain waste of memory and CPU cycles. You can use [file system functions](http://es.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) to read it as a regular file, such as [readfile()](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

It's also worth noting that using PHP to deliver a file only makes sense if you want to do something else as well, such as:

- Restricting access to the file
- Keeping a counter

Comment: Thanks! (Will accapt as soon as allowed)