# Save the output image into a different directory, with a new filename and extension

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, image, wordpress-theming

Let say I have this code in my *"image.php"* file that will create a new GD image stream and output an image:

```
header ('Content-Type: image/png');
$im = @imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20)
      or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Here's my sample diagram:

> file -> /root/template/program/image.php
>
> directory -> /root/template/images

How can I save the outputted image of *"image.php"* into the *"/images"* directory, with a different filename and extension like *"file.png"*?

Comment: I've followed [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8382125/4883372) but I get a _"file.png"_ that have a 0 byte size on disk. _"...can't open this picture because the file appears to be damaged, corrupted..."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **filename parameter**
>   The path to save the file to. If not set or NULL, the raw image stream
>   will be outputted directly.

I found a solution, just add a second parameter filename to the `imagepng()` function:

```
imagepng($im, '../images/file.png');
```